# TYPO3 upgade error - 6.2 LTS to 7.6 LTS

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

I have a TYPO3 website version 6.2.32 LTS and I want to upgrade it to the version 7.6 LTS.

I downloaded the package from Github and I did :

- change the symlink of the new /typo3/ folder
- change the symlink of the new index.php file
- execute the `rm -rf typo3temp/*` command

Problem : I get a 500 Error message when I navigate to "www.mywebsite.com/typo3/install" and I don't have access to the Apache logs to help me debugging. But when I open the `/typo3/install/index.php` file I notice :

```
require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
```

I do not use composer in my website then there is no `/vendor/` folder.
Is this my issue ? How to solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Github you've downloaded the composer-version.
Delete the downloaded version and replace it by this one:
https://get.typo3.org/version/7

Comment: :) Works great ! Thank you !